# In Wordpress, how do I stream updated status information in real time?

Tags: javascript, json, wordpress, real-time

I have a custom back end program that puts out status messages a few times a minute.  Currently, these are saved to a file.  However, I can save only the latest status message to a file if that helps.  I can also format the status as an XML or json message.

These status messages are intended to update a member that is logged in to a WordPress membership site. In other words, each member would receive status messages that are unique to them.  I'm running a instance of the back end program for each member and the status file is unique for each member.

Is there a way to display these status messages without reloading the WordPress page?  Or, is there a way to get the page to reload ONLY when a new status message is ready to be displayed?  There are a lot of Javascript frameworks that may be useful.  Any recommendations about which ones work well for this situation?

Comment: The back end is written in C, so https://libwebsockets.org/ should work on the back end?

Answer (score 0):

the term your are looking for is `WebSocket`, you'll have a program keeps running at server and it will keep connections between browsers and server.

However, since you are using WordPress which is PHP based, things may be a little bit harder.

PHP does not native have API for `WebSocket`, so implementing it is not as easy as other server side language like NodeJS.

But there are still libraries like [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/) you may use.

Once you've done the server side, browser side is much easier. you can use either [native JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) or many libraries that have better implementation.

Other than `WebSocket`, the old way to implement this is called `long polling`, which request server once in a while to see if there's anything new. It maybe easier to implement but is not recommended.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I saw some reference to websocket in my 5 hours of googling before I asked the question.  I'm working building a websocket test. Also,  I assume you mean "long polling" instead of "long pulling?"

Comment: yeah, sorry for the typo